# AWK: Find a sentence in one file and replace it with a sentence from another file

Tags: awk

I have two files: `file1` and `file2`

`file1`:

```
alpha
bravo
charlie  //comment 1
delta
victor   //comment 2
zulu
.
.
```

`file2`:

```
kirk
mike  //new comment 1
some  
phil  //new comment 2
.
.
.
```

How can I replace **comment 1** in file1 with **new comment 1** in file2
and **comment 2** with **new comment 2** and **so on**.

*Note  : Number of comment lines are equal on both the files.*

*Note 2: Using awk.*

*Note 3: comment is a string. It can be anything.* 
          **eg: charlie //likethis**

**What I did:**
I was just starting, So, I was trying to first achieve it with files having single comment.

```
awk -F\/\/ '{sub("//.*", "(cat file2 | grep "//")", $0); print $0}' file1
```

**Desired Output:**

```
alpha
bravo
charlie  //new comment 1
delta
victor   //new comment 2
zulu
.
.
```

Comment: Can comments contain `//`? Can the non-comment parts of your files contain `//` (they could if, for example, this was C or C++ code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the matching cannot be based on the content of the comments but on the number of the comment within the file (i.e., first comment, second comment...) and if only the comment has to be replaced, try this

```
awk -F"//" '(NR==FNR && NF>1){a[++i]=$2}
            (NR!=FNR){if(NF>1){print $1 FS a[++j]}
                      else{print $0}}' file2 file1
```

Note the order of arguments: `file2` before `file1`.
This will give the desired output:

```
alpha
bravo
charlie  //new comment 1
delta
victor   //new comment 2
zulu
```

**Update:** Here is a more "bullet-proof" version which allows comments within comments (e.g., `charlie // comments start with // and are followed by text`)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="//"}(NR==FNR && NF>1){$1="";a[++i]=$0}
            (NR!=FNR){if(NF>1){print $1 a[++j]}
                      else{print $0}}' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if($2){a[i++]=$2}next}
     $2{$2=a[j++]}1' FS='//' OFS='//' file2 file1
```

**Explanation**

`NR==FNR{if($2){a[i++]=$2}next}`: This part takes care of `file2` if we find that the field that contains the comment has a value (`if($2)`) it will be stored in an array (`a`) preserving the order, `next` statement is used to avoid rest of the *rows* of further processing.

`$2{$2=a[j++]}1`: process `file1` **only** when the **2th** field, the comment, has a value, replacing it with the one stored in the array used for `file2` using the `index` in the same order.

Finally `1`, is just a helper to print **all** `file1` records (modified or not by the previous `$2=a[j++]`), in `awk` when an *expression* is evaluated to `true` (`1` in this case) the default action is `print`the affected record.

`FS='//'` and `OFS='//'` sets the separators to the value of the comment marks.

**Results**

```
alpha
bravo
charlie  //new comment 1
delta
victor   //new comment 2
zulu
```

Comment: Unless you're changing values between files, for clarity you should init variables at the start of the script rather than at the end and when setting multiple variables to one value it's more robust to init them together instead of separately so use `BEGIN{FS=OFS="//"}` instead of after the script. Arrays start at 1 so pre-increment the indices. It will fail for comments that contain `//` (e.g. `bob // comment 3 // is a problem`) and obviously if you're running this on C or C++ code there are non-comment code constructs like strings that can contact `//` and so will break with this approach.